# Iterator and templates

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++11, iterator

I try to manipulate iterators.

```
template <typename Mytype>
class Myclass
 {
   public:
   Myclass ( const Mytype & myarg)
   {
    this->data=myarg;
   }
   ~Myclass ( void ){}
    set<int> Test ( const Mytype & myarg ) const
    {
      set<int> result;
      typename Mytype::iterator it=myarg.begin();
      return result;
    }
   private:
    //
    mutable Mytype data;
 };
```

This code is compiling.But when I want to use it, it is no longer compiling:
here is an example:

```
int main()
 {
    Myclass <string> t0 ( "caacaa" );
    set<int> r=t0.Test("a");
    return 0;
 }
```

I now get an error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘std::set<int>
Myclass<Mytype>::Test(const Mytype&) const [with Mytype =
std::basic_string<char>]’:
test.cpp:38:26: instantiated from here
test.cpp:25:48: error: conversion from
‘std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator {aka
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ requested
```

I tried to figure out what was wrong but I don't understand the error.

Comment: try changing this line `typename Mytype::iterator it=myarg.begin();` to `typename Mytype::const_iterator it=myarg.begin();`

Comment: @EdChum: Or even easier: `auto it = myarg.begin();`.

Comment: @rodrigo yes, didn't spot the c++11 tag

Comment: It is now working. Thank you. What does the const change for the iterator?

Comment: You're not allowed to change the entry it points to, which makes sense because you passed the container as const reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a const member function, the member data are const too. So you need to use `const_iterator`:

```
typename Mytype::const_iterator it = myarg.begin();
```

because `myarg.begin()` returns const iterator, because `myarg` is const, because member function is const.

Even better use `auto`:

```
auto it = myarg.begin();
```

But then you *still* need to know `it` is const — `auto` helps you to *avoid* typing the long name, not knowing the fact that `it` is const.